# Ebay authentication with Ruby

Tags: ruby, authentication, sinatra, omniauth

I'm developing eBay Sinatra application and need to authenticate an user by their login and password to give them the ability to request their information from eBay by themself. By authentication I mean authentication by redirection (or something like) to eBay and entering their login and password. It's similar to Facebook authentication.

I did a research but found almost zero. 
Your suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Omniauth](http://www.omniauth.org/) has a [strategy for ebay authentication](https://github.com/TheGiftsProject/omniauth-ebay). I haven't used it but omniauth is a competent gem for handling different login strategies for various sites out there. Recently I have used omniauth with rails but a couple of months ago I did likewise with padrino so I think it should work nice with pure sinatra also.

Comment: Is that gem going to work with Sinatra?

Comment: yes it should. It is supposed to work with any Rack based middleware. There is even a bit of example code on the home page for sinatra. But I don't have any personal experience of using it with sinatra.

Comment: I barely understand what Rack is. Can you explain me shortly or can you give a good link where that explaining?

Comment: I looked around a bit and found the [resources section of rails guide about rack](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html#resources) to have a good set of pointers to various resources about rack.